# TSLint and RouterLinkStubDirective errors when we follow Angular Official Guide

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I was trying to mock `RouterLink` and I found a guide on Angular's official [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#stubbing-the-routerlink). After adding, it somehow solved my issue but it raised two more.

1. TS Lint started pushing out a few errors.

   ```
   [tslint] The selector of the directive "RouterLinkStubDirective" should have prefix "abc" (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-08) (directive-selector)

   [tslint] Use @HostBindings and @HostListeners instead of the host property (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-06-03) (use-host-property-decorator)

   [tslint] In the class "RouterLinkStubDirective", the directive input property "linkParams" should not be renamed.Please, consider the following use "@Input() linkParams: string" (no-input-rename)
   ```

   [image]
2. It's not letting me create a directive without adding it in ngModule because of JIT compiler.

   Adding RouterLinkStub solved my test issue but it broke my app. Now my app is throwing following error because of JIT.

   ```
   ERROR in : Cannot determine the module for class RouterLinkStubDirective in /Users/usmantahir/Workspace/abcApp/src/app/testing/stubs/router-stubs.ts! Add RouterLinkStubDirective to the NgModule to fix it.`
   ```

   I tried to find a solution. I found one [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13590#issuecomment-279691337) so I tried it like this

   ```
   import { Directive, Input, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

   @Directive({
     selector: '[routerLink]',
     host: {
       '(click)': 'onClick()'
     }
   })
   export class RouterLinkStubDirective {
     @Input('routerLink') linkParams: any;
     navigatedTo: any = null;

     onClick() {
       this.navigatedTo = this.linkParams;
     }
   }

   @NgModule({
     declarations: [
       RouterLinkStubDirective,
     ]
   })
   class StubModule {}
   ```

   but it didn't solve it but started throwing this error in the browser.

   `TypeError: modules[moduleId] is undefined`

I solved this error by importing main app module inside this stub module like this.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    RouterLinkStubDirective
  ]
})
export class FakeRouterModule {
}
```

and this is one sample of test where I started facing this issue at the first place.

```
class RouterStub {
  navigate(url: string) { return url; }
}

describe('ReviewAddressComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ReviewAddressComponent>;
  let component: ReviewAddressComponent;
  let el: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        ...CombineComponents,
        RouterLinkStubDirective
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ReviewAddressComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    el = fixture.debugElement;
  });

  it('should create the component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    expect(el).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Now the question is,

1. **Is angular's own documentation is misleading or I am doing something wrong here.**
2. **Is there any other good way to solve this routerLink
   issue.** ie. `routerLink is unkown for <a>`
3. **Will this stub module affect my application in any way? performance or any glitch in running?**

Comment: 1) Every lint are correct : don't use host in decorator but @HostListeners, rename linkParams to routerLink and finaly add disable lint comment for the first error (all own directives must start with your prefix).
But why to you need to stub this directive ?

Comment: to make routerLink identifiable while running unit tests. Else it says `routerLink is unknown to <a>`

Comment: and I followed this solution from angular's official documentation. 

https://angular.io/guide/testing#stubbing-the-routerlink

Comment: Can you put a test example in your question ? Because I personally use real routerLink on unit tests. You probably miss RouterModule on your test.

Comment: Where do you imports your StubModule ? AppModule ?

Comment: I've added the test example and I never import my stub module anywhere.

Comment: 1) Add exports[] into your stub module that contains same as declaration. 2)  remove RouterLinkStubDirective in declaration of your test and add StubModule in imports of your test.

Comment: But I think if you put RouterModule in imports array of your test (after ReactiveFormsModule), you will not have "routerLink is unkown for <a>" anymore